# AIX command to kick out warning light

Tags: monitoring, aix, hardware

I am using very old **HMC V7**; I cannot upgrade this HMC and I have a problem.
I just cannot remove the warning light of my server vio via HMC after a hardware replacement.

I heard that there's a possibility to do that with an AIX command or via smit.

```
oslevel -s
6100-07-03-1207
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does the VIO server have open alerts on the HMC?

Comment: I tried to follow this indication : [ibm support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/POWER8/p8haj/aixlightoff.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I have find one solution for one of my vio.
But i still cannot remove alert for an other vio which have maybe a firmware problem.

```
/usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault -s normal
```

to set the system attention indicator back to normal state again

```
/usr/lpp/diagnostics/bin/usysfault -t
```

to see a list of available hardware indicators

Or with the command **diag** ->

- Log in as root user.
- At the command line, type **diag** and press Enter.
- From the Function Selection menu, select **Task Selection** and press
  Enter.
- From the Task Selection menu, select **Identify and Attention Indicators** and press Enter.
- From the list of lights, select the location code for the part and press Enter. When a light is activated for a part, an **I character** precedes the location code. Select Commit.